# Masking and indexing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe about crime statistics, where i want to mask and count the total number of crime values in my dataset:

```py
min = 0
max = 24

days = df[::24].count()['Year']
print(days)
df['daily_crime'] = np.NAN

for i in range(days):
    #print(df.loc[df.index[24], 'daily_crime'])
    print(df[min:max][df['Personfarlig_krim'] == 'Yes'])
    max += 24
    min += 24
```

Above I have placer a min and max counter, for each of the 24 hours in a day, i want to add an extra column to my dataframe, that counts the amount of `Yes` counts in the `Personfarlig_krim` for the last 24 hours. This row should be placed every day in a seperate column. I have tried both masking and slice, and then assigning a given row, but i have no luck so far.

```
Unnamed: 0  District    Neighbourhood.x Year    Month   Day Hour    Weekday Sun Personfarlig_krim   Date2
0   1   1   MANHATTAN   2015    4   1   0   4   False   No  2015-04-01 00:00:00
1   2   1   MANHATTAN   2015    4   1   1   4   False   No  2015-04-01 01:00:00
2   3   1   MANHATTAN   2015    4   1   2   4   False   No  2015-04-01 02:00:00
3   4   1   MANHATTAN   2015    4   1   3   4   False   No  2015-04-01 03:00:00
4   5   1   MANHATTAN   2015    4   1   4   4   False   No  2015-04-01 04:00:00
```

Above I have tried formatting the data. It is supposed, to have another column, that has the crime rate for the last 24 hours (24 rows) stored.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hm, that is a good question. To be frank - I am not really sure if I am knowledgeable enough on the matter, to provide a qualified answer.

Comment: @JonasGrønbek Thank you very much, dear sir. As a respected member of the Data Science and Deep Learning community, I very much respect your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date2"])
df["day_total"] = df.groupby(["Year","Month","Day"])["Personfarlig_krim"].transform(lambda d: sum(d.eq("Yes")))
print (df)

   District Neighbourhood.x  Year  Month  Day  Hour  Weekday    Sun Personfarlig_krim               Date2  day_total
0         1       MANHATTAN  2015      4    1     0        4  False                No 2015-04-01 00:00:00          0
1         1       MANHATTAN  2015      4    1     1        4  False                No 2015-04-01 01:00:00          0
2         1       MANHATTAN  2015      4    1     2        4  False                No 2015-04-01 02:00:00          0
3         1       MANHATTAN  2015      4    1     3        4  False                No 2015-04-01 03:00:00          0
4         1       MANHATTAN  2015      4    1     4        4  False                No 2015-04-01 04:00:00          0
```

Change the values back to 0 for results less than 24:

```
df.loc[(df.groupby(["Year","Month","Day"])["day_total"].transform("count").ne(24)),"day_total"] = 0
```

Comment: `Length mismatch: Expected axis has 74975 elements, new values have 74976 elements`

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Try `lambda d: sum(d.eq("Yes"))` instead of `lambda d: d.eq("Yes").sum()`. Reason probably due to [this](https://html.developreference.com/article/11618348/Why+does+sum+and+lambda+sum+differ+in+transform%3F).

Comment: issue still occurs :(

Comment: and `lambda d: np.sum(d.eq("Yes"))`? Where do you have `NaN` in your data?

Comment: Oh it works now perfect. The problem though is, that for the first 24 rows (24 hours), the sum should be equal to 0, because, there has not been a full 24-hours yet.

Comment: I think, that justs sets all numbers to 0?

Comment: It sets the days with a total count of less than 24 to 0. Unless you have a custom hour range, in that case just modify `ne(24)` to whatever number you see fit.